# strongSwan VPN Intermediate Certificate Authority

Tags: linux, windows, ipsec, certificate-authority, strongswan

I have been testing out strongSwan VPN on a Linux server in a Windows Active Directory domain.

I have managed to get a single-tier PKI with EAP authentication to work, but when I attempt to add a intermediate certificate authority to the setup connecting to the VPN fails.

The VPN and both CA's are Debian 9 boxes.

I have already taken this whole test domain down and I am getting ready to start over from scratch and was wondering if any one had any input on what I might be doing wrong.

Heres the commands I ran to create the CAs and server key pair.

Creating root CA private key:

```
$ ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 4096 --outform pem > ca.key.pem
$ chmod 600 ca.key.pem
```

Create self-signed certificate:

```
$ ipsec pki --self --flag serverAuth --in ca.key.pem \ 
  --type rsa --digest sha256 \
  --dn "C=US, O=IT_Testing, CN=VPN Root CA" --ca > ca.crt.der
```

Create intermediate CA private key:

```
$ ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 4096 --outform pem > intca.key.pem
```

Generate intermediate CA CSR:

```
$ ipsec pki --pub --in intca.key.pem --type rsa >  intca.csr
```

Sign the intermediate CA CSR:

```
$ ipsec pki --issue --cacert ca.crt.der \ 
  --cakey ca.key.pem --digest sha256 \
  --dn "C=US, O=IT_Testing, CN=INT CA" \
  --san "intca.testdomain.com" --flag serverAuth \ 
  --flag ikeIntermediate --outform pem \
  < intca.csr > intca.crt.pem
```

Create the VPN server private key and CSR:

```
$ ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 2048 --outform pem > vpn.testdomain.com.key.pem

$ ipsec pki --pub --in vpn.testdomian.com.key.pem --type rsa > vpn.testdomain.com.csr
```

Sign the VPN server certificate:

```
$ ipsec pki --issue --cacert intca.crt.pem \ 
  --cakey intca.key.pem --digest sha256 \
  --dn "C=US, O=IT_Testing, CN=vpn.testdomain.com" \
  --san "vpn.testdomain.com" --flag serverAuth --outform pem \
  < vpn.testdomain.com.csr > vpn.testdomain.com.crt.pem
```

I copy the root CA certificate to `/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts`, the VPN certificate to `/etc/ipsec.d/certs`, and the VPN server key to `/etc/ipsec.d/private`.

I add the line `leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/vpn.testdomain.com.crt.pem` to `ipsec.conf`. As well as point `ipsec.secrets` to the VPN server's private key.

The rest of the config is the same as the working single-tier pki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When issuing the intermediate CA certificate make sure you add `--ca` to the command line to add the CA basicConstraint and actually create a CA certificate.

And don't add the `serverAuth` and `ikeIntermediate` flags to it, only add them to the server certificate. `ikeIntermediate` does not refer to intermediate CA certificates, but IPsec intermediate systems, and it's probably not necessary to add it anymore (it was only [defined in a draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ipsec-pki-req-05#section-3.1) and I think only very old version of macOS required it).